# When are IndexedDB operations executed?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

In the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) to IndexedDB I find examples like this

```
// Let us open version 4 of our database
var DBOpenRequest = window.indexedDB.open("toDoList", 4);

// these two event handlers act on the database being opened
// successfully, or not
DBOpenRequest.onerror = function(event) {
  note.innerHTML += '<li>Error loading database.</li>';
};

DBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  note.innerHTML += '<li>Database initialized.</li>';

  // store the result of opening the database in the db
  // variable. This is used a lot later on, for opening
  // transactions and suchlike.
  db = DBOpenRequest.result;
};
```

As far as I understand, this first creates a request object and then defines two callbacks. But it never calls any code to execute the request. Still it seems to execute it sometime.

I am especially interested in the details, as it seems to be complicated to run different transactions after each other as transactions seem to be asynchronous.

Comment: "But it never calls any code to execute the request." - what do you mean by this?

Comment: Also, I agree that IndexDB's API design is nonintuitive and nonergonomic. It predates the adoption of the `Promise` type and `async/await` in JS, but fortunately there are plenty of `Promise`-based wrappers over IndexedDB which are much easier to work with: e.g. https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb

Comment: Using one of the libraries mentioned at the very bottom of the mdn doc link you provided makes dealing with IndexedDB a lot simpler

Comment: Google themselves [recommend using Jake's IndexedDB wrapper instead of using IndexedDB directly](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb), too.

Comment: Unless there's an error calling `open()` I don't think either of the callbacks should be triggered.

Comment: @Barmar It does - it's just horribly unclear. In actuality (and as-per my understanding), the `open` call pushes a "Task" onto the JS task queue rather than executing immediately, hence why it's okay to wire-up the `onerror`/`onsuccess` callbacks _after_ the initial call - but the callbacks must be added before the current "Task" completes (i.e. in the current function, or at least before control is returned to the browser).

Comment: @Dai (not a comment on the wrapper itself) Well, Jake works for Google, so...

Comment: Thank you all, I think the suggested answer helps. On the other hand this probably means one cannot use the developer console to debug it?

Comment: When you know how to use IndexedDB in the browser console, you can add an answer or a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70997675/how-to-run-indexeddb-queries-in-the-developer-console).

Comment: @allo You can use the console, just have it in multiple-statement mode (instead of single-line mode), or use `await` in the console with the `Promise`-based wrapper instead.