# How to run IndexedDB queries in the developer console?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, browser, indexeddb

The IndexedDB API uses the strange pattern to define callbacks after the open (and I think the transaction) call and seems to rely on the browser to first assign the callbacks and then really run the open call ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226505/doubts-about-html5-indexeddb-async-api)).

Now this is troubling, when I'd like to put some code in the browser developer console to query the database, especially when I want to run two queries after each other, which then seem to have a race condition. I already had before problems with error messages about already closed transactions and so on.

Is there a simple way to "just" sequentially run a few queries after each other?

Comment: You do know that you can enter multiple statements into a single console input line, right?

Comment: Also, you could just use the `Promise`-wrapper over IndexedDB and invoke _that_ from the console line-by-line (as you can use `await` in the console too: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-62/#await )

Comment: @Dai That's what I am doing, but together with a loop that should sequentially open transactions and some code to process the results, I seem to get race conditions. And, of course, debugging gets much harder, when you always have to copy 30 lines of code and run them at once instead of being able to run it line by line. So I would prefer some easy way to just sequentially query data stores. In the end I would not even need callbacks. A simple query method that blocks until the data is retrieved would be fine.

Comment: @dai I am not sure if this actually works for IndexedDB (in the related bugs people said that the IndexedDB API is not using promises) and I would (also) need a method that works in Firefox.

Comment: identifiers you define on `window` are accessible from the command line, just create the function you want, assign to window, e.g. `window.myFunction=`, then invoke it from console using `myFunction()`